# Getting The Start and End Time MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I'm trying to Retrieve data that can determine the Start and end date and view the changing interval of petname

Here is my sample data.

[image: Raw Data]

Here is my expected output

[image: Expected Output]

I tried to query like this

```
    SELECT 
    `line`, `Petname`, MIN(`start date`), MAX(`end date`)
FROM
    `tablename`
WHERE
    timestamp BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND NOW() group by petname
```

but my output return like this

[image: tried query]

Comment: Why do you want Petname `FKN92B` and `FKN8LD` to show up twice in your results?

Comment: i want to show that the petname change by time.

Comment: Where does it indicate that Petname changed for `FKN92B` for example? Are you saying non-continuous days indicate a new result row should show?

Comment: for example. from 1am to 2am im using Petname FKN92B then after wards 2am to 3am I change petname to FKN8LD then 3am - 4am I return to FKN92B so my timeframe would be

FKN92B start date - 1am end date 2am
FKN8LD start date - 2am end date 3am
FKN92B start date - 3am end date 4am

Comment: Does Petname change to `FKNAJK` or is that a different Petname altogether? More important: where does the DB store information about whether a given Petname indicates a *new* pet, or simply a different name for an *existing* pet? Without that info, your query is impossible.

Comment: FKNAJK is a different petname. all petname are given and ready to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the create sql of your table, therefore I create one just for test.
The following are my verification table. It may be different with yours, please modify according to your own table.

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+
| id | petname | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
|  1 | FKN92B  | 2020-07-01 | 2020-07-02 |
|  2 | FKN92B  | 2020-07-02 | 2020-07-04 |
|  3 | FKN8LD  | 2020-07-04 | 2020-07-05 |
|  4 | FKN8LD  | 2020-07-07 | 2020-07-08 |
|  5 | FKN92B  | 2020-07-11 | 2020-07-12 |
|  6 | FKN92B  | 2020-07-12 | 2020-07-14 |
|  7 | FKN8LD  | 2020-07-08 | 2020-07-09 |
|  8 | FKN8LD  | 2020-07-11 | 2020-07-11 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The SQL is as folloing, please have a try and let me know if there are any issues:

```
mysql> SET @lastpetname := null;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @groupnum := 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select petname, min(start_date), max(end_date)
    -> from
    ->     (SELECT
    ->             case
    ->                when @lastpetname is null then @groupnum := @groupnum + 1
    ->                when @lastpetname != petname > 0 then @groupnum := @groupnum + 1
    ->                else @groupnum := @groupnum
    ->             end as group_num,
    ->             @lastpetname := petname as petname,
    ->             `start_date`,
    ->            `end_date`
    ->     from `petlog`) t
    -> group by group_num;
+---------+-----------------+---------------+
| petname | min(start_date) | max(end_date) |
+---------+-----------------+---------------+
| FKN92B  | 2020-07-01      | 2020-07-04    |
| FKN8LD  | 2020-07-04      | 2020-07-08    |
| FKN92B  | 2020-07-11      | 2020-07-14    |
| FKN8LD  | 2020-07-08      | 2020-07-11    |
+---------+-----------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```